# How to control and get specific data when read XML file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, xmlreader

Good afternoon,
i have this XML file:

``````
<SpectraMagicNX_data>
    <data_set version="2" cdate="2020-12-10T11:34:52+00:00" observer="10">
        <sample>
            <group name="Test1">
                <item name="article">OA</item>
                <item name="number">1</item>
                <item name="state:">Fail</item>
            </group>
            <group name="Test2">
                <item name="article">0B</item>
                <item name="number">1</item>
                <item name="state:">Aprove</item>
            </group>
        </sample>
    </data_set>
</SpectraMagicNX_data>`````
``````

And i want when **article value equals 0B**, show the **state** value. **Aprove** in this case

Code

``````
        Do While (reader.Read())
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element
                    If reader.HasAttributes Then 'Se existirem atributos
                        While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                            If reader.Value = "OA" Then
                                MsgBox(reader.Value)
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                Case XmlNodeType.Text
                    MsgBox(reader.Value)
            End Select
        Loop`````
``````

I don't know if i'm using the best way, but i want something simple to understand.

**Reader.Value** basically show every Attribute value and i can't control that. And so i want to know how control **Group**, item and his value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using a variety of features. It selects a  node based on an item.  It then gets the state for that item.

```
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' xe = XElement.Load("path to XML here") 'for production use this
    'for testing use literal
    xe = <SpectraMagicNX_data>
             <data_set version="2" cdate="2020-12-10T11:34:52+00:00" observer="10">
                 <sample>
                     <group name="Test1">
                         <item name="article">OA</item>
                         <item name="number">1</item>
                         <item name="state:">Fail</item>
                     </group>
                     <group name="Test2">
                         <item name="article">0B</item>
                         <item name="number">1</item>
                         <item name="state:">Aprove</item>
                     </group>
                 </sample>
             </data_set>
         </SpectraMagicNX_data>

    ' select the first <group> that has an item with a 
    '  name attribute="article" and value of OA

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ' use LINQ
    ie = From el In xe...<group>.<item>
          Where el.@name = "article" AndAlso el.Value = "OA"
          Select el.Parent Take 1

    If ie.Count = 1 Then
        Dim ItemState As String
        ItemState = (From el In ie(0).Elements
                     Where el.@name = "state:"
                     Select el.Value).FirstOrDefault.ToString
        Stop 'look at ItemState
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, you showed a tutorial in C # of linq-xml-overview. Is there in XML? or where can i see more examples of using linq? Because if i want to shoe every item in group on itemstate what i need to do?

Comment: @PedroPinheiro - at the top of the page there should be a dropdown that lets you change the language.  Mine says VB.  Follow the links for more information.  You can also utilize this search   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=xelement&scope=.NET